# How resilient is modern Rails to the antipattern "thread + fork"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, puma

I think this is a popular antipattern that happens either standalone, for example activeJob local task with async, or coming from controllers, because then the strategy of the server must be taken into account.

My question is, what cautions should one take in the code when forking inside a thread (think inside of a ActiveJob task) and then even threading it?

The main worries I have seen online are:

- Needs to lose and reopen the database connections after the fork. It seems that nowadays activeRecord takes care of it, doesn't it?
- Access to the common Logger could be complicated. Somehow it seems to work.

Concurrent was expected to be problematic too but current versions are patched to detect that a fork has happened and threads are dead. Still it seems that one needs to make sure of doing, at the end of the forked process, a fine shutdown of any Rails::Concurrent pool that could have active or pending jobs. I think that it is enough

```
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.shutdown
```

but perhaps it could miss some tasks that have not started or tasks under other Concurrent queue. In fact I think it already happens if one uses Concurrent::Future in a controller managed by the puma webserver. Generically I try to insert

```
Concurrent::global_io_executor.shutdown
Concurrent::global_io_executor.wait_for_termination
```

Extra problems I have found are resource-related: the postgres server is not ready to manage so many connections by default. Perhaps it could be sensible to reduce the size of the connection pool before the fork. And the inotify watcher gem also exhausts resource, when launched in development. Production is fine in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR; - I'm against doing it but many of us do it anyway and ignore the fact that it's unsafe... things break too rarely.**

It is a simple fact that calling `fork` in a multi-threaded process may cause the new child to crash / deadlock / spin and may also cause other (harder to isolate) bugs.

**This has nothing to do with Ruby**, this is related to the locking mechanisms that safeguard critical sections and core process functionality such opening/closing files, allocating memory and any user created mutex / spinlock, etc'.

#### Why is it risky?

When calling `fork` the new process inherits all the state of the previous process but only the thread that called `fork` (all other threads do not exist in the new process).

This means that if any of the other threads was inside a critical section (i.e., allocating memory, opening a file, etc'), **that critical section would remain locked for the lifetime of the new process**, possibly causing deadlocks or unexpected errors.

#### Why do we ignore it?

In practical terms, the risk of something seriously breaking is often very low and most developers hadn't both encounter the issue and recognized its cause. Open files can be manually (if not automatically) closed, which leaves us mostly with the question of critical sections.

We can often reset our own critical sections which leaves mostly the system's critical sections...

The system's core critical sections that can be effected by `fork` are not that many. The main one is the memory allocator which can hardly ever break. Often the `malloc` implementation has multiple "arenas", each with its own critical section and it would be a long-shot to hit the system's underlying page allocation (i.e., `mmap`).

#### So is it safe?

No. Things still break, they just break rarely and when they do it isn't always obvious. Also, a parent process can sometime catch some of these errors and retry / recuperate and there are other ways to handle the risks.

#### Should I do it?

I wouldn't recommend to do it, but it depends. If you can handle an error, sure, go ahead. If not, that's a no.

Anyway, it's usually much better to use IPC to forward a message to a background process so that process perform any required `fork` / task.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern can occur naturally when a Rails controller is combined with a webserver. The situation is different depending if the webserver is threaded, forked or evented, but the final conclusion is the same; that it is safe.

Fork + fork and thread + fork should not present problems of multiple access to the database or multiple execution of the same code, as only the current thread is active in the children.

Event + fork could be a source of troubles if the event machine is still active in the forked thread. Fortunately most designs generate a separate thread for the control of the event loop.

Comment: It might be safe if no concurrent code is running, but  multi-threads + `fork` is never safe.